# AWS CLI command add condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, command-line-interface

I need to alter a resource based policy for AWS Lambda.

I need it to change from:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "S3Events",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:123456789123:function:Manage-configurator",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::managebucket"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "S3Events",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:123456789123:function:Manage-configurator",
      "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
        "AWS:SourceAccount": "123456789123"
    },
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::managebucket"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After researching im not sure how to add just an extra condition in

Answer (score 0):

To edit policies in AWS, you simply supply a completely new policy. There is no API that supports modification in place.